# Representation of symmetric function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I am interested in learning a bit more about symmetric functions of $n$ variables, namely functions that are invariant under permutation of their arguments : $\forall \pi \in \sigma_n$,
$$f(x_1,...,x_n) = f(x_{\pi(1)},...,x_{\pi(n)})$$

When $f$ is a polynomial or a rationial function, it can be written in a unique way as a sum of elementary symmetric polynomials or rational functions. This is the fundamental theorem of symmetrical functions (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofSymmetricFunctions.html for instance).

What can be said about a symmetric function that is not a polynomial or a rational function (only $C^\infty$ or analytic for instance) ?

Comment: I think in the case of analytic functions that if you represent the coefficients as an $n$ dimensional array, it will be symmetric.

Comment: Okay. I was more hoping for something resembling the fundamental theorem of symmetric functions. It would probably look like "there exists a unique analytic (or $C^\infty$) functions such that $ f(x_1,...,x_n) = g(e_1,...,e_n)$ where the $e_i$ are elementary symmetric polynomials". But I'm looking for a more solid evidence than just intuition.

Comment: The formulation of the fundamental theorem of symmetric function in the question is extremely sloppy. It is not a sum of such and such, but a polynomial/rational function in terms of those (elementary symmetric functions).